# How to make every variable in Matlab workspace accessible to every function?

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, callback

When I am running a Matlab script from command window, it is running correctly. This script uses functions, so I had to make variables global.

Now, when I am running this script from callback function of a toggle button in GUI, I am getting errors. Errors seem to be coming from variables being in accessible.

Am I missing something ? Whats the solution to this kind of problem ?

Comment: Please include the error message and code to reproduce the problem. I have no idea what you are doing. What do you mean with "This script uses functions, so I had to make variables global."? There is no need to make variables global when calling functions.

Comment: @Daniel : You're right, it's not necessary to make variables global when using functions, but since large no. of variables are being used, I m making them global instead of passing them. Error reads that variables are undefined when running script from GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a script from a callback function, the script has access to the workspace of the "caller" function, i.e. the callback function workspace, not the base workspace. You need to make sure each function has access to the variables it needs, either by making them global, or preferentially by passing them as arguments to the functions. This way, the code is much more portable, and doesn't rely on what variables may or may not exist in the base workspace. In a GUI, you can use the `handles` structure to store the data necessary for the callback functions to execute.

Comment: I had tried that way but was still getting errors. After reading your answer, I realized that errors were seeming to come from variables being undefined, but in reality, they were undefined due to some logical errors. Thank you very much!